# Why does google vision take so much time to train the model?

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, computer-vision, google-vision

I have been learning gcp and how to use google vision to train, test and evaluate a model over the image data set. I have been testing the model for just 60 images, Split as shown in the image. The estimated time to train has been over 60-90 min. I have been wondering what happens in the backend that it takes so much time to train.
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, if you do not provide enough images, the algorithm will tend to converge to an heuristic solution. This may take more time due to the low statistical significance of the trained data ingested, especially per label given your warning...

Comment: What I have read in the documentation that it takes more longer time when more images are trained

Comment: Hi! Your slowness can be due to what your log and the documentation says [link](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/prepare), that you should have for each label at least 10 images.